# OneDrive API - Sharepoint - Make calls against a URL root

Tags: onedrive

Referring to OneDrive API documentation [here](https://dev.onedrive.com/getting-started.htm), the section `Make calls against a URL root` has table that references to the SharePoint Online Service noting its url is:

```
https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/{site-relative-path}/_api/v2.0
```

What does the `{site-relative-path}` refers to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how familiar you are with SharePoint but `{site-relative-path}` is the relative path to the Team Site. So if you have a Team site called "Contoso" and it is located at `https://testTenant.sharepoint.com/sites/contoso` then the relative path would be `/sites/contoso`

Comment: Where is the word "Contoso" assigned to the Team site? Is it the site's Title?  Sharepoint is such a bear to wrestle with.

Comment: After I authenticate I can manually enter  `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/v1.0/` into browser and get response. But there is no response from  `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/contoso/_api/v1.0/` (assuming 'contoso' refers to the site Title)

Comment: This was just an example. A Team Site must be created by an end user. If you are working in an actual SharePoint Online tenant, this site probably will not exist, so you will have to try one that does exist in your tenant.

Comment: I was just using 'contoso' as placeholder for my site Title (which is something like 'My Team Site')

Comment: In reference to this [Sites documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Organize-documents-and-sites-in-Office-365-1a36030f-3e54-4c43-8401-b7bcd0d1c16b) where it says `Select Sites in the header, select the Team Site tile, and then select a Documents library in the Quick Launch bar at the side of the screen.` Is this 'Team Site'  what you are referring to as a 'Team Site'? And would its `{site-relative-path}`  be `/sites/Team Site`  ?

Comment: Yes. `Team Site` is just a nomenclature, in the same way some one could have a cat named Jerry. `Team Site` is the name of the  that live within SharePoint. To abstract it a bit if SharePoint is an array then a `Team Site` is like a element, its just a place to store the information. And as for how the site path will look is dependent on what is provided when the Team Site is created. So it could look like the example you provided.

Comment: So I have a Site in my Office 365 E3 account Sites, which was there by default, named 'Team Site'. I have never used it before until now, when I created a new folder which I called 'Test Team Site Folder'. When I looked at new folder path it was `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/contentTypeHub/Shared%20Documents/Test%20Team%20Site%20Folder`  Where is the `contentTypeHub` name assigned? Can it be changed?